# Reopening Unity project after two week break, project is trashed

Tags: unity

I've spent about 6 months using Unity nearly every day. Then I take a two-week break, re-open my project, and the entire build is trashed.

There are 166 errors, here are a few:

```
Assets\TextMesh Pro\Examples & Extras\Scripts\ChatController.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The 
namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'ChatController'



private Renderer renderer;Assets\Scripts\Board\Tile.cs(23,22): warning CS0108: 'Tile.renderer'      
hides inherited member 'Component.renderer'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.



Assets\TextMesh Pro\Examples & Extras\Scripts\ObjectSpin.cs(8,18): error CS0101: The namespace 
'TMPro.Examples' already contains a definition for 'ObjectSpin'
```

I've re-imported Text Mesh Pro Examples & Extra, restarted my project multiple times, to no avail. This is very concerning to me because it makes me feel like Unity is not a stable plaform ... Are Unity projects attacked by gremlins if not used every couple days?

Comment: Did you get it fixed?

Comment: Did you change Unity versions from when you last saved the project? You didn't mention whether or not it's still the same version of Unity, but that certainly matters.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Unity projects are not corrupted after being left for a couple days. But, this can depend on a few factors, such as if you are using a LTS **(Long Term Support)** version of Unity or a standard version that updates commonly. If you are using a version that updates commonly, certain packages that worked one day can stop working the next, due to bugs, and so on. This same issue you are having has happened to me before. I recommend removing all your packages from the `Package Window` and removing the package cache. This worked for me.